# Targeting first visible element with pure CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering if it is possible to transpose the following into pure CSS.

```
$('.child:visible:first').css({'border-top':'1px solid #cccccc','border-bottom':'1px solid #cccccc'});
```

I cannot seem to find a solution.

Comment: no you can't do it with pure css

Comment: I believe it's impossible

Comment: If you can add classes to your visible elements (.visible/.hidden) it becomes possible but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was not possible but I thought I would ask anyway.  Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pure CSS, no it's not possible. Chris Coyier has *:first* listed as purely a jQuery construct:   http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/.

Answer (score 48):

As an abstract, it's not possible: jQuery relies on traversing the DOM to programatically determine an element which fits various conditions, then stops. You can't do this. But I assume in practice you will know various things. This solution assumes:

1. You know *how* these `.child` elements are going to be hidden. Will they have `display: none` as an inline style (if you've used jQuery `.hide()` on them, they will)? Do they have a class of `.hidden`? As long as you know the method, there will be a selector you can use to represent this. You can use this in combination with the CSS3 `:not()` selector.
2. Since these are called `.child`, I'm assuming they're all siblings — none are nested inside other `.child` elements, and they all share the same parent.

If either of the above isn't true, it's impossible. But if they're both true:

```
.child:not( [style*='display: none'] ) {
    border-top:    1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.child:not( [style*='display: none'] ) ~ .child:not( [style*='display: none'] ) {
    /* ...or whatever the default styles are */
    border-top:    none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

The `:not()` pseudo-class is fairly obvious: it only selects elements which *don't* match the contained selector. The `~` operator means that the selector to the right will be the target *if* it is a sibling of the selector on the left appearing afterwards in the source code.

Comment: #1 is the key. You can't use a selector to determine whether an element is hidden or visible; you have to rely on some other information that can be matched with a selector that will guarantee that for you.

Comment: Yes, it's inevitable (I think I was fairly explicit about that). However the assumption is *not* unreasonable. If the author is working within a controlled codebase, there will be a standardised method for hiding these elements: the use case implies it. If the code is for a plugin that can't make any assumptions about the codebase (and the given scenario is just an abstract), then we're out of luck.

Comment: I suppose you added `.child,` in line 6 by mistake? It matches every child, so the styles are applied to all children.

Answer (score 17):

It is posible if you know how it is implemented the hiding.
For instance, this would select the first visible element after a block (+1) of hidden elements:

```css
li[style*="display:none"] + li:not([style*="display:none"]) {
  /* ... */
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="display:none">hidden</li>
  <li style="display:none">hidden</li>
  <li>visible, selected</li>
  <li>visible, not-selected</li>
  <li style="display:none">hidden</li>
  <li>visible, selected</li>
  <li>visible, not-selected</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But what if there are two hidden items, or three, or an indeterminate number, before the first visible item?

Comment: In this example, the "+" sibling combinator will target whatever is directly next to the last hidden element in the DOM, so it doesn't matter how many hidden elements are before the visible one.

Comment: This solution is incorrect in general, as well as the comment about several siblings. The pseudo-class `:first-child` always selects the very first sibling without testing conditions, NOT the first result among the ones you expected to narrow down with the rest of the conditions. Then this selector will always attempt to match the second sibling and maybe succeed or not depending on the visibility conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and comments on this 8 years old answer :) 

I confirmed that if you remove the `:first-child` piece it will then successfully select the first visible element that is after **EACH** hidden element.

Updated response.

Comment: If you only to only style the visible element only on the first visible block, you can reset the style of the additional blocks by adding this selector and applying the appropriate style:

`li:not([style*="display:none"]) ~ li:not([style*="display:none"]){ background: red }`

Answer (score 10):

try this  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2fkhj7pu/4/)

```
ul li{
    background: lightslategrey
}
li:first-child{
  background: blue;
}
ul li[style*="display:none"] + li:not([style*="display:none"]){
  background: blue;
}
ul li:not([style*="display:none"]) + li{
  background: blue;
}
ul > li:not([style*="display:none"]) ~ *{
  background: lightslategrey!important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome, with one change: a space added between display: none... [style*="display: none"]

Comment: This only works if the first li element is hidden. If there are two or more li's with display: none, this does not work. You would need to do something nasty like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ct8doq3f/1/ and be sure you cover all possible lengths of the field.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, that follow-up example is solid gold 

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I only had to give padding before the first **li**
I was able to achieve that with the following code.

```
ul:before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

But if you want to give li specific css, then you will have to following the tricks mentioned in other answers.

All my **li** elements expect the first had a border-top.

So if my first li was hidden, the second element still showed the border-top.
I updated the above code to ensure all **li** elements have border-top, and I just hid the first border-top using margin trick

```
ul {
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -1px; // (update as per the width of your border-top)*
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

If your border-top is 3px, then margin-bottom will be -3px, and add that to the height to balance (18px).

These are just tricks since CSS doesn't have had a *:visible* selector

Answer (score -1):

I had a case when either one of the 2 top buttons of a list of buttons was visible, applying the style to both solved it:

```
.bt:nth-child(1), .bt:nth-child(2) {
   ...
}
```