# Re-apply css rules for first visible row on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change css style for the first visible row on a table using jQuery and css rules.

When i change the offset i would like to show first visible table TBODY row in red using my css rule.

this is my code example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('change',function(){
    $.each($("tbody>tr"), function(index, element) {
             offset =  $('input').val();
             if(index < offset){
                $("#row-"+index).removeClass('is-visible');
             }else{
                $("#row-"+index).addClass('is-visible');
             }
        });
  })
});
```

```css
table tbody>tr{
  display:none;
}
table tbody>tr.is-visible{
  display:block;
}
table tr.is-visible:first-child{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
offset : <input type="number" min="0" max="100">
<hr>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>TH 1</th>
   <th>TH 2</th>
   <th>TH 3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-0">
   <td>0</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    
    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-1">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-2">
   <td>2</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-3">
   <td>3</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-4">
   <td>4</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-5">
   <td>5</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>5</td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Pure css it's not possible:- [Targeting first visible element with pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765814/targeting-first-visible-element-with-pure-css)

But through jQuery you can do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('change',function(){
    $.each($("tbody>tr"), function(index, element) {
       offset =  $('input').val();
       if(index < offset){
          $("#row-"+index).removeClass('is-visible');
       }else{
          $("#row-"+index).addClass('is-visible');
       }
    });
    $(".is-visible:first").css({"background-color":"red"});
    $(".is-visible").not(":first").css({"background-color":"#ffffff"});
  })
});
```

```css
table tbody>tr{
  display:none;
}
table tbody>tr.is-visible{
  display:block;
}
table tr.is-visible:first-child{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
offset : <input type="number" min="0" max="100">
<hr>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TH 1</th>
      <th>TH 2</th>
      <th>TH 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-0">
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-5">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do using jQuery. Try below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('change',function(){
    $.each($("tbody>tr"), function(index, element) {
             offset =  $('input').val();
             if(index < offset){
                $("#row-"+index).removeClass('is-visible');
             }else{
                $("#row-"+index).addClass('is-visible');
             }
             $(".is-visible").css({"background-color":"white"});
             $("#row-"+offset).css({"background-color":"red"});
        });
  })
});
```

```css
table tbody>tr{
  display:none;
}
table tbody>tr.is-visible{
  display:block;
}
table tr.is-visible:first-child{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
offset : <input type="number" min="0" max="100">
<hr>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>TH 1</th>
   <th>TH 2</th>
   <th>TH 3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-0">
   <td>0</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    
    <tr class="is-visible" id="row-1">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-2">
   <td>2</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-3">
   <td>3</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-4">
   <td>4</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr class="is-visible" id="row-5">
   <td>5</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>5</td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see: https://jsfiddle.net/dkhny7t9/3/